# Camera tracking data import

Tags: camera, import, tracking

Is there a way to import camera tracking data, like .json or .jsx files into Blender?

Comment: Welcome to [blender.se], please make sure to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this the other way round and export to After Effects (*.jsx) using the [Adobe After Effects plugin](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.5/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Adobe_After_Effects/) but it hasn't been updated for 2.80.

This has been investigated before please see [Does Blender 2.8 have a working import-export plugin for After Effects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120610/442)

The only truly supported format for tracking data import is *.bvh, again via add-on.

You can always modify the jsx script to import instead, but as it stands I donn't know of any native way to do what you ask.

Perhaps look at this addon from the blendermarket

https://blendermarket.com/products/ae2blend

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I've tried that Atom pyton script, but I get stuck in script errors when running it in Blender 2.8... I'm trying out the AE2Blend add-on now.. Kind of hard to use (for me at least), but think it might work...

Comment: Please see added link to [Does Blender 2.8 have a working import-export plugin for After Effects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120608/does-blender-2-8-have-a-working-import-export-plugin-for-after-effects/120610#120610)